# Как перевести массив в многоуровневый объект (javascript)

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть массив:

```
var authority = [
    "Дзержинським",
    "РВ",
    "у",
    "місті",
    "Харкові",
    "ГУ",
    "ДМС",
    "України",
    "в",
    "Харківській",
    "області"
]
```

Необходимо на его основе получить многоуровневый объект вида:

```
var obj = {
    "Дзержинським": {
        "РВ": {
            "у": {
                "місті": {
                    "Харкові": {
                        "ГУ": {
                            "ДМС": {
                                "України": {
                                    "в": {
                                        "Харківській": {
                                            "області": {

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Массив может быть разной длины, следовательно объект может иметь больший/меньший уровень вложенностей.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать при помощи цикла? Или возможно есть более правильное решение данной задачи?

Кроме такого больше ничего в голову не приходит :(

```
var tempObj = {};

tempObj[authority[0]] = {};
tempObj[authority[0]][authority[1]] = {};
tempObj[authority[0]][authority[1]][authority[2]] = {};
tempObj[authority[0]][authority[1]][authority[2]][authority[3]] = {};
tempObj[authority[0]][authority[1]][authority[2]][authority[3]][authority[4]] = {};
tempObj[authority[0]][authority[1]][authority[2]][authority[3]][authority[4]][authority[5]] = {};
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight), заворачиваем каждую итерацию аккумулятор в свойство нового объекта под именем элемента массива.

```js
var authority = [ "Дзержинським","РВ","у","місті","Харкові", "ГУ", "ДМС","України","в","Харківській","області"];
let result = authority.reduceRight((acc, el) => ({[el]: acc}), {});
console.log(result);
```

—-

> upd

сокращенная форма записи лямбды в сниппете эквивалентна функции `reduceRight` :

```
authority.reduceRight(reduceFunc, {});

function reduceFunc(accumulator, element) {
     var newAccumulator = {};
     newAccumulator[element] = accumulator;
     return newAccumulator;
}
```

Comment: +1 .Как ты так быстро написал ответ ?) У меня было похожее решение жаль =(

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов так одна строчка же

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а зачем тут `({[el]: acc}), {});` в конце `{}` вот это (пустой объект) я не понял?Не разу не видел такой reduce

Comment: @Demon__ANT вторым аргументом в reduce, можно передать аккумулятор, я передал пустой объект, если этого не делать аккумулятором становится первый объект из сворачиваемого массива и свертка происходит со второго элемента массива. Что касается `=> ({})` это сокращенная запись лямбды, чтобы не писать ключевое слово return  `=> {return {}}`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  очень сложно и запутанно   спасибо все равно.

Comment: @Demon__ANT я дополнил ответ

Answer (score 3):

```js
var a = ["Дзержинським", "РВ", "у", "місті", "Харкові", "ГУ", "ДМС", "України", "в", "Харківській", "області"]

var res = {}, x = res
for (var key of a) x = x[key] = {}
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: `.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }` неплохо

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, это уже [44й](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178988+.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper) ;)

Comment: ну не видел я =), может еще шрифт уменьшать?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, так в сниппетах шрифт не регулируется ((

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WQhf8II.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а, вот ты про что) А я думал, ты хочешь строчке css-кода шрифт уменьшить, чтоб не выделялась)